# How can I enumerate questions on math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I'm writing on overleaf.com and tried \tag#, where is the number of the equation. Here's exactly what I did: $$E=\vec p^2+m^2 \tag1$$.
Any ideas on how to do it?

PS: I should say I'm not positive wether it really is math mode. I'm just repeating everything I see on physics and math stackexchange pages and this is the first time it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you load the amsmath package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) and [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) both use MathJax to render their math content. This requires the use of the following syntax

```
$$
  <math>
$$
```

for display math content, and `$<math>$` for inline math content. While this does work for MathJax, you need a little more in order to write an equation with tags using Overleaf:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

Display equation without label:
\[
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c
\]
The above is similar to
\begin{equation*}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c.
\end{equation*}

Display equation with label to \eqref{eqn:quadratic1}:
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \label{eqn:quadratic1}
\end{equation}

Display equation with custom label to \eqref{eqn:quadratic2}:
\begin{equation}
  f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \tag{quadratic} \label{eqn:quadratic2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```